# GET request with Basic Authentication, Why Does This Not Work?

Tags: python, http, networking

I'm trying to read the data from a webpage with basic auth, but my get request doesn't work for some reason. The line:

```
cmd = "GET {} HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: {}\r\n\r\n{}".format(path, host, header_auth)
```

seems to be the problem but I feel like I'm doing everything fine. Can someone help? Is something wrong with my header, because I'm getting 401 Unathorized as the response. Thanks in advance.

```
#to run program on console, write:
#run CloudDownloader.py dijkstra.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~cs421/descriptor1.txt cs421:bilkent
import sys
import socket
import base64

args = list(sys.argv)
url = sys.argv[1]
url_elm = url.split("/",1) #elm[0] = base url, elm[1] = path
url_elm[1] = "/" + url_elm[1]
host = url_elm[0]
path = url_elm[1]
userpass = str(sys.argv[2]) #.split(":")
token = base64.b64encode(userpass.encode()).decode()
print(sys.argv)
sock1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock1.connect((host, 80))
header_auth = "Authorization: Basic " + token
#cmd = "GET {} HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: {}\r\n\r\n{}".format(path, host, header_auth)
lines= ['GET %s HTTP/1.1' % path,'Host: %s' % host,'Authorization: Basic %s' % token,'Connection: close']
cmd = "".join(str(elm) for elm in lines)
sock1.send(cmd.encode())


while True:
    data = sock1.recv(512)
    if len(data) < 1:
        break
    print(data.decode())
sock1.close()
```

Comment: It looks like you've placed your auth header *after* the `\r\n\r\n` end-of-headers marker. It needs to go before that.

Comment: @larsks you have saved my life, I literally have been stuck here for the last 2 days and couldn't find any answer. thank you so so much <3